# Column Name of dynamic object

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

How can I get the header (columns Name) of a dynamic List ?

here is my code

```
  var Participants = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<dynamic>>(obj.ToString());
```

and I need to get the name of all the column inside the var `Participants`

Any ideas ?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using `dynamic`?

Comment: If you know the concrete type deserialize to that type.. Then you will know all the properties. If you don't know the type then using reflection, and only in runtime, you will know the property names

Comment: I'm using dynamic because , the column's name isn't static, actually it's a date

Answer (score 0):

Use `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty`, take for example you have the following json object:

```
{ "summary" : { "123": {}, "456": {} } }
```

You want to deserialize to a list of the following:

```cs
class SomeClass {
  public string ID {get;set;}
}
```

Your code would be:

```cs
dynamic responseDynamic = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

List<SomeClass> someList = new List<SomeClass>();

foreach (var item in responseDynamic.summary)
{
    string id = ((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty)item).Name;

    someList.Add(new SomeClass(){ID = id});
}
```